# Number of possible results with rolls

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, dice

I have tomorrow a Combinatorics exam and I am practising with an exercise which asks me to find how many possible results are there if we throw $6$ identical dices so that there must be at least one three. I think is really simple, however, I'm not still sure:

One begins using inclusion-exclusion principle, which would be the cardinal of the total set $A$ of possible results minus the cardinal of another set $B$, which is the set of results in which no three appears. For the first cardinal, it is the same as putting the results in order and a bar between two numbers when those two numbers and different. If a certain number does not appear, we put two bars together. Therefore, one has $5$ bars to put into $(6+5) = 11$ positions, and therefore we have $11\choose 5$.

For the second cardinal, it is the same but taking into account that now there are $5$ possible numbers, therefore a bar less and a position less to choose, which leads to $10 \choose 4$. The final result would be ${11 \choose 5} - {10 \choose 4}$. Is this right?

Comment: When you say result, do you mean an ordered sextuple $(x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5, x_6)$ of dice rolls?  Please clarify.

Comment: Yes if you consider the dice as identical. The use of "dice" in this question is very unorthodox, as this usually implies different probabilities are accounted for. It's clearer to say "there are six pieces of paper and we're writing integers 1-6 on them". But of course I'm just nitpicking the question here.

Comment: Yes, it is a sextuple of possible numbers.

Comment: @DanielC. wait, a sextuple implies the dice are distinguishable because they're distinguishable by position in the sextuple! Are you sure this is what you meant?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood it. Then it's not a sextuple, just six numbers whose order does not matter

Comment: Just to be sure everyone understand same problem : if we don't have the constraint 'at least one 3', what is the total number of results.

Comment: [[ Assuming it is sextuple ]] There are $6^6$ ways to roll the dice. In that , there are $5^6$ ways where 1 number ( in our case , that number is 3 ) will not occur. Hence , total number of ways where that number ( 3 ) occurs at least 1 time is $6^6-5^6$ which is easy to calculate. We can check whether your calculation matches numerically with this value. [[ Assuming it is not sextuple ]] We can still calculate the total ways & then remove the ways where that number will not occur.

Comment: To me, the words "throw $6$ identical dice" (or roll) seems to imply that each die throw/roll  may show any number $1-6$ unifornly at random,

Answer (score -1):

Cardinal of $A$ is $6^6$, because each of the six dices has $6$ numbers on it. The cardinal of $B$ is $5^6$, because each of the six dices has $5$ favorable situations.

When throwing dices the order is important. For example, if we throw 2 dices, the pair $(1,2)$ is different of $(2,1)$, because the first position is for the first dice and the second position is for the second dice.

Comment: I might have made a mistake with the languaje. In this case, order it is supposed not to be important. I should have said "roll" then

Comment: Then, I would say that we choose a subset with six element of a set with six of $1$, six of $2$, six of $3$, six of $4$,six of $5$ and six of $6$. This can be done in $\binom{36}{6}$.  The case when $3$ does not appear is similar to choosing a subset with six element of a set with six of $1$, six of $2$, six of $4$,six of $5$ and six of $6$. This can be done in $\binom{30}{6}$.

Comment: I believe, this is the right answer to the wrong question. If you care about computing probabilities, it is best to use a sample space of size $6^6$ where all outcomes are equally likely. For this problem, we are not worried about probabilities, and all that is needed is to compute the number of outcomes up to reordering.